# Is there something similar to PgPool-II for oracle

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling

I am running apps in kubernetes, which for even one app, it may have multiple containers; thus, the jdbc pool won't work.
Is there a layer similar to PgPool-II for oracle database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you interested in just the "Connection Pooling" feature or do you want a comparison to all features?

Comment: Mostly for the connection pooling feature, and it will be great if the apps can still use jdbc protocol

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

Connection Pooling - feature of the database, [Database Resident Connection Pooling](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/drcp.htm#JJDBC29023)

Limiting Exceeding Connections - limiting connections, feature of the database, [PROFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310). Connection queuing, no such thing.

The above 2 are typically handled at application server layer.

Replication - disk mirroring can happen independently of the database, or using [Automatic Storage Management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ostmg/asm-intro.html#GUID-BC612D35-5399-4A35-843E-CF76E3D3CDB5), feature of the clusterware layer. For physical/logical replication, feature of the database: [Introduction to Oracle Data Guard](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sbydb/introduction-to-oracle-data-guard-concepts.html#GUID-5E73667D-4A56-445E-911F-1E99092DD8D7). For logical replication, feature of the database: [Introduction to Oracle Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17069/strms_over.htm), or other products such as [Oracle Goldengate](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/goldengate.html).

Load Balancing - feature of the clusterware layer, [Load Balancing of Connections to Oracle RAC Databases](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/rilin/load-balancing-of-connections-to-oracle-rac-databases.html#GUID-06B4373D-1217-44E4-BD86-DE353DA657F6)

Watchdog - feature of the clusterware layer and the database, [Introduction to Oracle RAC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/racad/introduction-to-oracle-rac.html#GUID-5A1B02A2-A327-42DD-A1AD-20610B2A9D92), [Introduction to Oracle Data Guard](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sbydb/introduction-to-oracle-data-guard-concepts.html#GUID-5E73667D-4A56-445E-911F-1E99092DD8D7), [Application Continuity](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_app_continuity.htm#ADFNS1058)

In Memory Query Cache - feature of the database: [Result Cache](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgdba/tuning-result-cache.html#GUID-FA30CC32-17AB-477A-9E4C-B47BFE0968A1)

Answer (score 0):

[Database Resident Connection Pooling](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc002.htm#ADMIN12348) sounds like the feature you seek.

> **When To Use Database Resident Connection Pooling**
>
> - Database resident connection pooling is useful when multiple clients access the database and when any of the following apply:
> - A large number of client connections need to be supported with minimum memory usage.
> - The client applications are similar and can share or reuse sessions.
> - Applications are similar if they connect with the same database credentials and use the same schema.
> - The client applications acquire a database connection, work on it for a relatively short duration, and then release it.
> - Session affinity is not required across client requests.
> - There are multiple processes and multiple hosts on the client side.

Some of the other features of PGPool-II would require "special configuration" or are "not applicable" due Oracle's architecture.

Eg

- Client Side caching requires the `/*+ cache */` hint and the right driver.  (OCI version, I believe)
- Instead of the "share nothing" architecture that PGPool-II uses, you would use Real Application Cluster (RAC) and Standby Databases

  - The Listener can do round-robin Load Balancing across nodes
  - Standby Databases can be made Read Only (with Advance Data Guard license)
  - Transparent Application Failover (TAF) automatically moves connections from failed node to another node